# How to pass custom strings and values to ExceptionNotifier in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception

I have the following code when rescuing from an Exception:

```
rescue Exceptions::LogoNotCroppable => ex
  logger.error "Logo was not croppable LogoID: #{self.id}. Exception message: #{ex.message}"
  ex.backtrace.each { |line| logger.debug line }
  # Send email with notification that something did not go as expected
  ExceptionNotifier.notify_exception(ex)
```

But how would I do it, if I want to pass something extra to that notification? For, example if I want to pass the self.id of the object that created the exception?

Comment: https://github.com/smartinez87/exception_notification#manually-notify-of-exception

Answer (score 2):

Using the data hash:

```
ExceptionNotifier.notify_exception(ex, :data => {:object_id => self.id})
```